# How to use Array.fill() with the same object but different copies for every index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I'm creating an array and populating it using the `fill` method but changing `array1[0].foo` changes all objects in the array.

```
const array1 = Array(2).fill({ foo: null })
array1[0].foo = 'bar' // [ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'bar' } ]
```

Is there a way to use `fill` with different copies of the same object for every index?

Comment: You mean different copies.  And, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work with [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), because it uses a constant value.

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and map the object.

```js
const array = Array.from({ length: 2 }, _ => ({ foo: null }));

array[0].foo = 'bar';

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Wow, that did work, thanks. To complement, I was cloning an array in the first place so it ended up `Array.from(oldArray, () => ({ foo: null }))`.

Comment: @Razär: Then you might as well call `.map()`.